# Facebook games will not work on xubuntu 11.10 how do I fix?

Tags: firefox, games, plugin, facebook

I just had xubuntu 11.10 put on my computer and know nothing about the system.

Adobe flash player is installed and up to date, I have only had this running for a few days. My YouTube works just fine but when I try to play a game on Facebook it tells me that my flash player needs to be upgraded. Being used to Windows, I went  into my Firefox plugin menu, and there is not even an adobe flash plugin listed. (I thought maybe it wasn't active)

I was wondering if/how this can be fixed? Can someone can explain it to me, even though I know absolutely nothing about the operating system?

Answer (score 1):

On (x)ubuntu you get your flashplayer upgrades through upgrades to the **system** via apt. (Package: flashplugin-installer). Since 11.10 is unsupported this will not happen and you have to see if there are non-official maintainers for your version of FireFox (You might have to upgrade FireFox to the latest version outside of using packages).

I would however first look into upgrading to a still supported version of (X)Ubuntu. Ask the person who put you up with that about it.